# Bootstrap 3 accordion expand/collapse stopped working with iPad screen reader enabled

Tags: ipad, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, accessibility

We're using Bootstrap 3 (v3.3.5) accordion and it works fine until the screen reader is enabled on the iPad (iOS v9.1).  Once the screen reader is enabled, the accordions will no longer expand/collapse for accordions with shorter labels (labels that take up less than 50% of the available space).  The shorter label issue is consistent as the screen is rotated between landscape and portrait.  The issue can be corrected by making the labels longer than 50% of the available space or centering them. Unfortunately, centering or expanding the label is not an option on our team.

This seems to be a problem with Bootstrap 3 and not Bootstrap 2. I pointed to the bootstrap 2 accordion example here (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse) and enabled the screen reader on the iPad and it worked fine.  Then, I pointed to the bootstrap 3 accordion example here (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) and enabled the screen reader on the iPad and it failed to expand/collapse the accordion.

Has anyone found a fix or another workaround? Perhaps, we are missing an attribute to fix the problem or something else.

Here is the code that we're using in our accordion:

```
<div class="row" id="A">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

      <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingA">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#contentA" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="contentA">This label is to short for any screen
          <span class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" id="toggleA">show content</span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="contentA" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingA">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>This label is to short to expand/collapse this content on any iPad screen with the screen reader enabled.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div> 

      <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingB">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#contentB" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="contentB">This label works on portrait/landscape screen and will expand/collapse accordion
          <span class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" id="toggleB">show content</span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="contentB" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingB">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>This label is long enough to expand/collapse this content on the iPad portrait and landscape screens with the screen reader enabled.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingC">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#contentC" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="contentC">This label works on portrait screen not landscape
          <span class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" id="toggleC">show content</span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="contentC" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingC">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>This label is long enough to expand/collapse this content on the iPad portrait screen but not the landscape with the screen reader enabled.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- End panel group -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: When you say "it failed", which action are you doing on the screen? single tap? double tap?

Comment: double tap.  The single tap still reads the label.  The double tap reads the label rather than expand/collapse the content.

Comment: This problem was finally resolved by someone on the team.  It was associated with the aria attributes.  They removed these attributes and it started working.  role=”tablist”, role=”tabpanel” and role=”tab”. They also remove aria-multiselectable=”true” but I don’t think that had any affect.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the following bug:

[Use of anchors nested in headings causes issues in VoiceOver, promotes anti-pattern usage](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16753)

> anchors within headings(H4) confuse VoiceOver(VO), which:
>
> - causes VO to place the VO cursor on the H4 vs. the anchor,
> - doesn't read any of the aria attributes on the anchor,
> - breaks the standard VO-Spacebar interaction

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this out but it still didn't allow the accordions to expand.  It turned out to be related to the aria attributes.  I listed the problems attributes above.